# how to fix an app that is not receiving push notifications because It's uploaded with push development profile

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've uploaded a iOs app to the app store but I almost 100%100 sure that I've uploaded with a development provisioning profile, and also development push certificates... And push it's not working anymore so I would like to ask a noob question.. ¿Do I need to upload a new app or its posible to fix this with an update? Also would like to know if I can fix this without an app update, only renewing certificates. 
Many thanks!

Comment: Does apple actually accept apps with development provision porfile? How did you upload your app?

Comment: Maybe I did a mistake but my push is not working anymore and don'y know why so I thougth it was that. Sorry guys

Comment: Did you made your own server for push notification? and you changed the `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` with `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195` ?

Comment: Yes I've allready did that but I still get error

Comment: So you didn't test that push was working *before* you submitted to the app store using the production environment and a production build?

Comment: I think that's the case. I forgot to switch to production environement

Comment: But  if you didn't switch to the production environment then pushes sent via the development environment would not be delivered to a device with a production build app installed on it. So you must have made a submission without first testing pushes worked with a production build. Anyway, that's besides the point now. I recommend you close this question as your issue is nothing to do with an app submission with a dev profile and open a new one to try to determine why your pushes aren't working. The issue is nothing to do with your original title/question anymore.

Comment: how do I close the question?

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe is not possible. You can only upload applications with Application Loader which are signed with an App Store distribution certificate. So the reason why your push notifications aren't working are caused by other problems. Did you already check the server which is sending them?

Comment: Yes I've checked with the server. I got this error: Failed to connect: 0. This error is in line 80 of my php code. This is my php code from lines 57 to 60: // Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
 $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
And this is line 80: if (!$fp)
 exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL .__LINE__);

Comment: Have you made sure that your server is using the production certificate and not the development certificate when you are connecting to the production environment?

Comment: I've created today a new production certificate and replaced my old ck.pem in server and I'm sure this time it was a production one, but what I'm not sure it's if I need to do some changes in my app (and what changes) because my app was working with development push certificates...

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to upload a new app. You can fix it with update.
You just need to replace your newly created .pem file with old one.
Hope this will help!

Comment: And if I lost my old one?

Comment: No problem. Just create new .pem file and give it to server.